# How to connect from inside of the Docker container to host OS?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, networking, docker-compose

My web app has a connection string like the following

jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my-template?useSSL=false

When running outside of Docker everything works as expected.

When I run/boot the application from Docker it doesn't connect to mySQL.

I get that Docker is a closed container VM but how do I allow it to find my mySQL instance?

I tried some things I read about like adding an extra_hosts entry but that didn't seem to work either.
jdbc:mysql://fc.database/my-template?useSSL=false

People must do this all the time right?

```
version: '3'

services:

  tomcat:
    image: 'local/myapp:r1'
    build:
      context: '.'
    
    volumes:  
      - './logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs'
    
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    network_mode: "host"
    extra_hosts:
      - "fc.database:127.0.0.1:3306"
volumes: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace 127.0.0.1 with `host.docker.internal` and try it again.
Actually, 127.0.0.1 pointed to myself so that the docker container will point to the docker container, not the host OS. but AFAIK `host.docker.internal` will point to the host OS.
Also, please take care of the host firewall. So check your OS firewall to allow incoming traffic on the desired port(3306).

Comment: extra_hosts:
      - "fc.database:host.docker.internal:3306 and my jdbc connection string as follows jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://fc.database/fc-template?useSSL=false and port open in firewall but still no luck

Comment: @Doug remove the extra host and try with jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/my-template?useSSL=false